# How to test if msg.value is 1 ether in test

Tags: solidity, unittesting, mocha, hardhat-deploy, chai

I have a function which mints when 1 eth is send to it. The function is

```
    function _mint() public payable{
            require(msg.value == 1 ether , "Send more ethers: 1 ether is required");
            require(balanceOf(msg.sender)==0, "You can not have more than 1 Land");
           .........
        }
```

I want to write a test which checks if 1 eth is send to it or not.
Please help if anyone can.

Comment: You said you want a test, in mocha, to see if the user sent 1 ether. But this is confusing. Mocha is for testing if a function is properly working or not, and not to check if a user sent 1 ether. I will supose you want to know if the function worked correctly. So you need to do a test that sends less than 1 ether and see if it reverted, and then call the function passing more than 1 ether and see if the function passed. Is this what you want?

Comment: My function should accept exactly 1 ETH neither less nor more. Rest you got it right.

Comment: then you should check the balance of the contract before (the contract is an account, so it will have a balance), the balance of the contract after, and assert if the difference in balance 1 ether.

Comment: This is also a good solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got the right idea, just keep in mind ETH has 18 decimals.

```
require(msg.value >= 1 * 10**18, "Must send at least 1 ETH");
```

Comment: I want to write a test to validate this. How can I write this test logic in mocha? This is the question.

Comment: Solidity accepts the keyword ether and does the conversion

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**
I finally figured it out.
This is how I wrote test for this case.

```
describe("Amount Received",()=>{
  it("Should only mint When 1 Eth is received",async()=>{
    let v = await (contractInstance._mint({value:1}));
    v.wait();
     expect( v.value.toString()).to.equal("1");
  })
});
```

I'm checking for 1 WEI instead of 1 ETH in this case to avoid BigNumber Error.